# Select Menu message collector returns interaction has already been acknowledged when ran twice

Tags: discord.js

The command that I'm trying to do this with is a help command with multiple sub-menu's like the FM-bot.
Whenever I run my command twice, it always returns `Interaction has already been acknowledged.`.

You have to select one of the sub-menus though first for this to happen, otherwise the command loads fine.

Here's the code for the command:

```js
            const categories = [
                {
                    label: `AniList Commands`,
                    description: `Show's you the AniList commands`,
                    id: 'anilist',
                    commandFolder: "anilist",
                    color: '#0099ff',
                    filterFn: (x) => x.endsWith(".js")
                },
                {
                    label: `General Commands`,
                    description: `Show's you the general commands`,
                    id: 'general',
                    commandFolder: "general",
                    color: '#ea9e07',
                    filterFn: (x) => x.endsWith(".js") && x != "help.js" && x != "birthday.js"
                },
                {
                    label: `Hentai Commands`,
                    description: `Show's you the Hentai commands`,
                    id: 'hentai',
                    commandFolder: "hentai",
                    color: '#fb2347',
                    filterFn: (x) => x.endsWith(".js")
                }
            ]

            function parseCategory(category) {
                const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, `../${category.commandFolder}`)).filter(category.filterFn);
                const commands = [];
                for (const file of commandFiles) {
                    const command = require(`../${category.commandFolder}/${file}`);
                    if (command.name && command.description && command.type) {
                        commands.push({ name: command.name, description: command.description });
                    }
                }
                return commands;
            }

            const row = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageSelectMenu()
                        .setCustomId(`1`)
                        .setPlaceholder(`Select one of the available categories`)
                        .addOptions(categories.map(category => {
                            return {
                                label: category.label,
                                description: category.description,
                                value: category.id
                            }
                        }))
                )


            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Here are all the bot commands`)
                .setDescription(`Select one of the command categories using the dropdown menu.`)

            await message.channel.send({ content: ` `, embeds: [embed], components: [row] })

            let categoryContents = {};
            for (const category of categories) {
                categoryContents[category.id] = parseCategory(category)
            }

            let categoryEmbeds = {};
            for (const category of categories) {
                const commands = categoryContents[category.id];
                if (commands.length > 0) {
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(`${category.label}`)
                        .setColor(category.color)
                        .setFooter(`${commands.length} commands in this category`)
                        .setTimestamp();
                    for (const command of commands) {
                        embed.addField(`${process.env.prefix}${command.name}`, `${command.description}`);
                    }
                    categoryEmbeds[category.id] = embed;
                }
            }

            let collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
                componentType: `SELECT_MENU`,
                idle: 10_000,
            });

            collector.on(`collect`, async (collected) => {
                let value = collected.values[0];
                await collected.update({ embeds: [categoryEmbeds[value]] });
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is with the collector, you are spinning up a new collector with `let collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector` without disposing of the collector for the last instance of the interaction. This means the first collector you establish is catching the `collect` event when it is emitted, make sure to use `collector.stop()` to dispose of the collector when the interaction is resolved.

Also you have an idle time of `idle: 10_000` on your collector which I do not believe is a valid amount of ms, probably just a typo of `10000`.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it was that so a while ago I tried messing around with stopping the collector, but the issue is I'm unsure when to stop the collector as I'd like it to be possible to use the command on a sever at the same time, and well.. I tried the simple solution of doing ```collector.stop()``` at the start of the issue, but as you can guess I got the ```Can't use collector before initialization```